# Only show unique results when selecting 4 tokens in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have the following response from SOLR, only the below tokens are selected, there's about 10 more, which would make each of these unique. What do I add to the query to get a result which is unique for what is the response?

Grouping wouldn't work as there is no column that can be used. The combination of CURRENCYCODE&CLIENTCODE&LANGUAGECODE work for grouping, but I couldn't figure out how to make that work.

```
    {
  "response":{"numFound":6,"start":1,"docs":[
      {
        "PRODUCTNAME":"Office Chair",
        "CURRENCYCODE":"EUR",
        "CLIENTCODE":"Northwind Inc",
        "LANGUAGECODE":"ENG",
        "KEYWORDS":"spins, adjust, castors"}
      {
        "PRODUCTNAME":"Office Chair",
        "CURRENCYCODE":"EUR",
        "CLIENTCODE":"Northwind Inc",
        "LANGUAGECODE":"ENG",
        "KEYWORDS":"spins, adjust, castors"}
      {
        "PRODUCTNAME":"Office Chair",
        "CURRENCYCODE":"EUR",
        "CLIENTCODE":"Northwind Inc",
        "LANGUAGECODE":"ENG",
        "KEYWORDS":"spins, adjust, castors"}
      {
        "PRODUCTNAME":"Office Chair",
        "CURRENCYCODE":"EUR",
        "CLIENTCODE":"Northwind Inc",
        "LANGUAGECODE":"ENG",
        "KEYWORDS":"spins, adjust, castors"}
      {
        "PRODUCTNAME":"Office Chair",
        "CURRENCYCODE":"EUR",
        "CLIENTCODE":"Northwind Inc",
        "LANGUAGECODE":"ENG",
        "KEYWORDS":"spins, adjust, castors"}
      {
        "PRODUCTNAME":"Office Chair",
        "CURRENCYCODE":"EUR",
        "CLIENTCODE":"Northwind Inc",
        "LANGUAGECODE":"ENG",
        "KEYWORDS":"spins, adjust, castors"}]
  }}
```

Comment: Index the currency code + client code + language code merged into a separate field and group on that? The preferred way to solve this issues for document search engines are usually to index the same content in different ways to solve specific use cases.